# Cant install php53 on OS X Mavericks using homebew

Tags: macos, homebrew, php-5.3, php, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install php53-fpm on OS X Mavericks

```
brew install php53 --with-fpm
```

Getting stacked at :

```
==> Installing dependencies for php53: gettext, jpeg, unixodbc, homebrew/dupes/zlib, libevent
==> Installing php53 dependency: gettext
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gettext/gettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading patches
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file gettext-tools/Makefile.in
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1551 (offset 51 lines).
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.3.1 --with-included-gettext --with-included-glib --with-included-libcroco --with-included-libunistring --with-emacs --disa
==> make
```

Seems like this file of 16M will compile forever. I stopped after 2 hours. Any Idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading xcode from the Appstore solved it somehow.